# how to get post value from multiple array in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to get value of post array in yii2,
I have array like this

```
[Brand] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => testing
                            [1] => jkhkjhjkhjk
                        )

                    [tagline] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => kjhjkh
                            [1] => 
                        )

                    [meta_keyword] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => 
                        )

                    [sort_order] => 
                    [image] => brand/1452498338552.jpg
                    [status] => 
                )

        )
```

I tried to get value with below function, but i am unable to get it.

`$request = Yii::$app->request;`

```
$request->post('Brand[name][0]');
```

How can i get value of name array ?
I don't want to use it like $_POST['Brand']['name'][0], I need to use only yii2 function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use [ArrayHelper class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html#getting-values)

```
$var = ArrayHelper::getValue($request->post(), 'Brand.name.0');
```

The way `$request->post()` method works, it just returns to you a value from `$_POST`, so usage is:

```
$brand = $request->post('Brand'); // now $brand variable contains $_POST['Brand']
$var = $brand['name'][0]
```

Comment: Would `Array
(
    [total_images] => 4
    [images_uploaded] => 1
)
` these two value can be returned from the same method ?