# How Do I loop through this POST array?

Tags: php, yii2

I have data that is being passed through an POST method. However when I try to get some data out of it and set it to a session variable, there is no data in it yet when I print_R($_POST) I see there is Data in it.

This is What I'm getting when I print_r() the POST data.

```
Array ( 
    [_csrf] => nXRvIHfHWeao64YBdwcdFJa3fz-KShIyAuHDNtKQqhCkDRdwErUqkOrSyHQQamtR5cBHWc57QUNq16hflaftKQ== 
    [LoginForm] => Array (
        [compayname] =>Termite Soup 
        [username] => Jim.Bot
        [password] => 123456 
        [url] => 
    ) 
    [login-button] => 
)
```

This is what I've tried.

This is the form where form is being filled.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'login-form',
        'layout' => 'horizontal',
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-10\">{input} 
        </div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-8\">{error}</div>",
            'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-3 control-label'],
        ],
     ]); 
    ?>

        <?php echo $form->field($model, 
  'compayname')>dropDownList(['GF_TB_TNT' => 'GF-TNT', 
        'Chicken Soup' =>'Dog Soup',
        'Termite Soup' =>'Termite Soup',
        ],

        ['prompt'=>'Select Company']); ?>



        <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'url')->hiddenInput()->label(''); ?>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="btn-group">
                <!-- <div class="col-md-2">
                </div> -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary pull-left', 'name' => 'login-button','style'=>'font-size: 15px;']) ?>
                </div>
```

Getting the data and setting it to a Session Variable

```
if (Yii::$app->request->post()) {
                $companyname = Yii::$app->request->post('compayname');

}
```

I want to set the companyname in the POST to a session Variable

Comment: You  can get data of `LoginForm` via `$data = $_POST['LoginForm']`

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717266/how-to-get-post-value-from-multiple-array-in-yii2

Your "compayname" post variable is inside an array on the post (LoginForm). Something like `ArrayHelper::getValue($request->post(), 'LoginForm.compayname.0');`

Comment: the filed in your model is "compayname" or "companyname"? Could it be a mispelling?

Comment: @BrettGregson Thank You. It has Worked Like  a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is

```
foreach (Yii::$app->request->post('LoginForm') as $field) {
// some logic
}
```

Also I see a mistake in compayname. A "n" is missing in the word. But you can access it's value by `Yii::$app->request->post('LoginForm')['compayname'];`

Comment: @KinyuaJames This should be the accepted answer, as the other one is not quite good. I know it sounds like advertising, but the accepted answer loops through the data and saves it in another array. This is really not needed and it is also waste of resources. Why would you allocate memory for a copy of an array you already have. If you really want to have another array with the `LoginForm` in it, you should just use `$arr = Yii::$app->request->post('LoginForm');`. The accepted answer is really a show of bad code practice. Also what is this empty `else` there.

Answer (score -1):

You can shortly get this.

```php
$arr = [];
foreach ($_POST as $param) {
    if (is_array($param)) {
        foreach ($param as $name) {
            if ($name == 'LoginForm') {
                array_push($arr, $name);
            }
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

And you can figure out how the data is structured using `var_dump`

```php
var_dump($arr);
```